# Not Getting In-App Purhcasing CallBack for KindleFire Android

Tags: android, api, in-app-purchase

I am stuck for 5 days regarding Inn-App purchase flow. I have uploaded a version with amazon in-app 3 months ago in Amazon store. It worked well. I was able to sell in-game items through it. But, few days ago, I launched a new version of it including amazon mobile ads. And surprisingly, my app was rejected due to in-app purchase error. I updated the code little, re-submitted (didnt update app version code and version name), but got the same bug report from amazon testing team. I don't have any clue about this. My previous version worked so well, and in this version, I maintained all the purchasing flow exact same.
There is a new settings in my developer portal called Security Profile. I have not include it in my app.Is that any related to in-app purchasing ? (I also included amazon game circle in my app).

The main problem is, amazon testing team is not getting live response i.e IAP API calls are not being performed in a "Live" mode. Means, onSdkAvailable() is returning false.

My code is exactly the same as their ButtonClicker example.
The receiver is properly set on the manifest.

I use following lines in proguard,

-keep public class com.amazon.**

-keepclassmembers public class com.amazon.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.amazon.**

As I dont have any real kindle fire device, so, resolving this issue is getting difficult for me. I am testing the app installing amazon test client in my android device. And, everything works fine there.

So my questions are,

1. How to make sure that IAP API calls perform in a "Live" mode ? Is there any settings which have to handle at amazon mobile distribution portal ?
2. Is updating version code and version name will solve that problem ?

Any other solution ?

Please help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

I had IAP application and checked with SDK tester and submitted, there was not a problem. Are you sure it is IAP problem, as your application was working fine previously. was it rejected for new api's which you added in the application.
Raise issue on amazon contactus (https://developer.amazon.com/help/contactus.html). those guys will answer. As they have records why your application got rejected. and the response is pretty neat.

Comment: Yes, it was ruuning well in previous version . Because, I got some purchase in previous version . But, I dont know what is the error in new version . There is no change in in-app purchasing flow ..

Answer (score 0):

after struggling, I had figure  out the actual problem.. 
In my proguard, I wrote, 
keep public class com.amazon

later, I define,
keep class com.amazon**

and my problem solve. So, that was a problem of pro-guard.